# Ocultar código y número de input y output en Jupyter al exportarlo como PDF via Latex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, markdown

Tengo un documento Python en Jupyter. Quiero descargarlo como PDF vía Latex y tratar de ocultar determinadas lineas de código y los números de INPUT[X] y OUTPUT[X].
En definitiva quiero que muestre solo los resultados de mis comandos de código.

Lo descargo de la siguiente manera: tomando "PDF via LATEX"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AL hacerlo así obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Es posible ocultar las lineas de código y el número de los inputs/outputs?**

También quiero poder añadir mi nombre al inicio del documento, debajo de la fecha.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente tu problema es que quieres que el notebook tenga un formato PDF "estilo libro".

Para esto hay una librería que suele ser muy usada en Ciencia de Datos que hace este trabajo llamada `nbconvert` (proviene de NoteBook Convert)

Para ello puedes instalarla mediante `pip` con el comando:

```
pip install nbconvert
```

O con `conda` con el comando:

```
conda install nbconvert
```

Puedes ver [aquí](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) el **proceso de instalación** por si te es necesario ampliar sus funcionalidades.

Una vez instalado para quitar el código, simplemente tendrías que ejecutar el siguiente comando en la terminal:

```
jupyter nbconvert /ruta/hacia/tunotebook.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt
```

- La opción `--no-input` quita las lineas de código.
- La opción `--no-prompt` quita los números y alinea celdas.

Por supuesto hay infinidad de opciones y plantillas (plantillas creadas con un determinado formato) para elegir. Puedes verlo en la [documentación oficial](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

### Extra

Como extra recomiendo aprender a crear/usar plantillas ya que te ahorrará más tiempo al futuro y te quedará mucho mejor. Además de que ya hay plantillas creadas que están muy perfeccionadas y queda todo de una forma muy representable.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Le echaré un ojo. Donde obtengo dichas plantillas?

Answer (score 0):

También puedes crear un botón que oculte todo el código de las celdas, pero no el resultado de la ejecución, con el botón también puedes volver a mostrar el código

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''<script>code_show=true; function code_toggle() {if (code_show){$('div.input').hide();} else {$('div.input').show();}code_show = !code_show}$( document ).ready(code_toggle);</script><form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" value="Ocultar/Mostrar Código"></form>''')
```